# AJAX Success Function using JS substr() fails in WP 4.1 vs 4.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, jquery-ui

For years I've set up php ajax calls and responses in my plugins like the following, 
with js error detection conditions as needed like...

```
if( "<e>" == msg.substr(0, 3) ) { do_something(); }
```

As of WP 4.1 However substr no longer works on the response string, though split does. Why?
The only major difference I see between the two is in the jquery/ui, but I wouldn't think that would affect ajax responses?

**MY_AJAX.PHP**

```
<?php
    die("<e>Foo");
?>
```

**My.js**

```
function test_msg(){
    $.post("my_ajax.php", "foo", function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.substr(0, 3)); //LOGS empty string (twice)
        console.log(msg.split(">")[1]); //LOGS "Foo"
        if( "<e>" == msg.substr(0, 3) ){console.log("Error");} //fails
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using custom endpoint? As presented there is no WP involved in your example at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't guess I Understand what you mean by custom endpoint.  Hoping it would suffice, that it was assumed, that within the context of a WP Plugin, there exists a properly enqueued script named My.js, containing a function named test_msg() having an ajax call containing a WP-appropriate URL to a php contained in a plugin file named MY_AJAX.php where the entirety of the construct worked as expected in EVERY version of WP since 2.2, but now doesn't in WP 4.1.

Comment: The baseline practice for Ajax in WP is using `admin-ajax.php` endpoint. So it is hard to guess what `MY_AJAX.php` is without way more context. :)

Comment: So basically, I've been implementing ajax all wrong for years:(
Something like http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#bad-ways

Comment: It'd sure be nice to understand what changed, that I might effect a patch While I learn to do it right, and get out of my bad habit.  Lot's of code to re-invent overnight.

Comment: Are there any other messages in the console that suggest an error? As mentioned, it is pretty hard to see what is going on here without more context.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW...
It APPEARS to have been a misconfiguration in the PHP.INI on a new Development Server (WAMP), which resulted in an unknown corruption of the code upon updating from wp4.0 to 4.1 such that PHP was injecting unwanted white space e.g. "\r\n\r\n..." in my AJAX responses (like a missing closing php ?> tag or someting?)

When running **ob_clean()** before returning an AJAX response, the problem went away, AND... when only the DEV copy of the project displayed the unwanted behavior, I copied the live site (wp4.1) to a mirror installation on the reconfigured DEV server, and all functions as expected.

Still, my practice of utilizing custom AJAX endpoints in future WP Projects is now officially deprecated ;-)